# jQuery remove all li elements with empty a childs

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove all `<li></li>` elements with an empty `<a></a>` tag?

Example:

```
<li><a href=''>List item</a></li> //Do not delete
<li><a href=''></a></li> //Delete
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could combine the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)/[`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) jQuery selectors:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/50ubcwwx/)

```
$('li:has(a:empty)').remove();
```

Comment: ^1 Good use of selector composition. Has is the right choice here in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Use following script

```
$("li a:empty").parent().remove();
```

For reference - https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 0):

To only remove `li` elements with empty `a` **children** use this:

```
$("li > a:empty").parent().remove();
//OR $('li:has(>a:empty)').remove();
```

Examples:

```
<li><a href=''>List item</a></li> <!-- not remove this -->
<li><a href=''></a></li> <!-- remove this -->
<li><span><a href=''></a></span></li> <!-- not remove this -->
```